# Synthesis of Code fails with no critical warnings or errors?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis, vivado

My following vhdl module will synthesize if I comment out the second process block, but if I try to use both of them, the synthesis will fail with no critical warnings or errors listed. 
There are some warnings, but they are just the usual things (no ethernet connected for the Zynq, things that aren't used,  etc.)

I can not see any reason why this would happen. Originally I had a for loop inside the process statement that was causing the errors, but taking that out did not work.
Then I thought that it might be a multidriven net between the two processes, but that is not the case either.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


use work.DataTypes_pkg.all;

entity EvalFUOutputs is 
    Port ( 
        Clk_Launch : in  std_logic;
        RESET : in  std_logic;
        start : in  std_logic;
        current_phase : in  PhaseType;
        ready : out  std_logic;
        init_or_captured : in  std_logic;       --mode bit
        all_timings_done : out  std_logic;
        Capture_vals : in  std_logic_vector(FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB-1 downto 0);
        Launch_MUXCtrl : in  std_logic;
        Capture_ClkEn : in  std_logic; 
        --2D array for results.
        row_timings : out RowResultsType;
        glitches : out  OutRowType
        );
end EvalFUOutputs;

architecture beh of EvalFUOutputs is

    type mode_enum is (init, eval);
    signal mode : mode_enum;

    type eval_enum is (idle, eval_begin, get_time, all_timed);
    signal eval_state : eval_enum;

    type init_enum is(begin_init, compare, done);
    signal init_state : init_enum;

    signal row_time : RowResultsType;

    type init_vals_declare is array (0 downto 1) of std_logic_vector (FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0);
    signal init_vals : init_vals_declare;

    signal has_been_timed : std_logic_vector (FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0 );
    --
    --  if 0 => will not change
    --  if 1 => will change
    --
    signal will_change : std_logic_vector (FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0);

    signal init_done :std_logic;

    signal fu_vals_changed : std_logic_vector (FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0);

    --
    --  This modules clock signal
    --
    signal clk : std_logic;

    signal a : std_logic;

begin

    clk <= Clk_Launch;



    mode_of_FU :
    process(clk, mode, RESET) is

    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if RESET = '1' then
                --TODO:RESET LOGIC
                mode <= init;
            else 

                case mode is 
                    when init =>

                    --
                    --  Check if need to change to next
                    --      nested state mahcine
                    --
                        if (init_or_captured = '1') then
                            mode <= eval;
                        else
                            mode <= init;
                        end if;

                    when eval =>

                    --
                    --  End EVAL LOGIC nested state mahcine
                    --
                        if (init_or_captured = '0') then
                            mode <= eval;
                        else
                            mode <= init;
                        end if;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;




init_state_machine:
process (clk, RESET,mode,init_state) is

begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
      if (mode = init) then 
        if RESET ='1' then
            --TODO reset logic
            init_state <= begin_init;
            init_done <= '0';

            else

                case init_state is
                    --TODO: init logic
                    --
                    --  1.A Init Machine Start
                    --
                    when begin_init =>
                        -- row timings set to zero to beign
                        row_time <= (others => (others => '0'));

                        init_vals(0)(FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0) <= Capture_vals;

                        if (start = '1') then
                            init_state <= compare;
                        else
                            init_state <= begin_init;
                        end if;

                    when compare =>
                        --wait one more clk cycle to get changed values
                        init_vals(1)(FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0) <= Capture_vals;

                        has_been_timed <= (others => '0');

                        init_state <= done;

                    when done =>
                        init_done <= '1';

                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;

--ready <= '1' ;
--all_timings_done <= '1';
--row_timings <= (others => (others => '1'));
--glitches <= (others => '1');
a <= '0';

end beh;
```

Here are the contents of DataTypes.pkg

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

package DataTypes_pkg is

   constant PHASE_SHIFT_LEN_NB: integer := 11;
   constant PHASE_SHIFT_RANGE: integer := 1120;
   constant PHASE_SHIFT_ZEROPHASE: integer := 0;

   constant FU_INPUT_WIDTH_NB: integer := 3;

   constant FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_LB: integer := 1;
   constant FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB: integer := 2;

   constant PHASE_LOWER_BOUND: integer := 150;
   constant PHASE_UPPER_BOUND: integer := 1100;

   subtype InRowType is std_logic_vector(FU_INPUT_WIDTH_NB-1 downto 0);
   subtype OutRowType is std_logic_vector(FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB-1 downto 0);

   subtype PhaseType is unsigned(PHASE_SHIFT_LEN_NB-1 downto 0);

   type RowResultsType is array(FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB-1 downto 0) of PhaseType;

   subtype row_index_type is integer range 0 to FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB - 1;

end DataTypes_pkg;
```

Comment: What's the Vivado version number?

Comment: Synthesis tools don't always give the best diagnostics of problems like this. That's OK, they don't have to : they can assume you've already tested the module in simulation. Have you?

Comment: Vivado 2014.4   @BrianDrummond I haven't. Vivado doesn't support VHDL timing simulations anymore,  and I don't have the time to learn verilog right now.

Comment: You shouldn't need timing simulations, ordinary behavioural sims (before synth) should detect the problem, and I'd be surprised if Vivado dropped that. You DO need to simulate to catch this because `0 downto 1` is a valid way of expressing an array with no members so it should synthesise to no hardware ... and apparently it does : so, NOT a Vivado bug. If you can't get along with either of the Xilinx simulators, try another sim such as ghdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type init_vals_declare is array (0 downto 1) of std_logic_vector (FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0);
```

Should be

```
  type init_vals_declare is array (0 to 1) of std_logic_vector (FU_OUTPUT_WIDTH_NB -1 downto 0);
```

Vivado will ***not*** tell you that the other way is wrong.

Comment: "Vivado will ***not*** tell you that the other way is wrong".  It's not an illegal, it just doesn't do what you want. If you had a tool that would check bounds for static expressions at analysis you'd find the two places the array type `init_vals` in the second process have bounds check errors, a null array has no elements (IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges). In some simulators the bounds check errors might be reported at run time. Vivado should have produced an error message somewhere, if not submit a bug. (And why couldn't that be `(1 downto 0)`?

Comment: Have you tried to define an unconstrained vector type (`is array(natural range <>)`) and then declared a signal of range `1 downto 0`?

Comment: @user1155120 Even if it is not technically illegal, it is wrong. If it wasn't wrong, it would synth, right? It does do  what I want, if I make "downto" into "to".  There is no reason why it couldn't be `1 downto 0` other than Vivado didn't tell me that part of the code was wrong. Reporting a bug though is futile, as I'm using 2014.4, and Xilinx doesn't care about anything other than current software.

Comment: @Paebbels Per your other comment, Vivado 2014.4.  As for this one, I had tried that before, but I couldn't assign to the signal the way that I needed to if I had done it that way.

Comment: Your synthesis tool may have failed to report an error.  Synthesis is nominally required  (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, now withdrawn) to simulate using non-metavalue stimulus to prove equivalence between their output and the design model, they likely don't do that for elements that get gate eaten.  The error would be discarding something because of a null range instead of flagging an error (and I'd search your logs carefully). If you can't rely on your synthesis tools to report (run time) language errors reliably, simulate first.

Comment: @user1155120 Yes, the syth did fail to report an error, as that is the premise of my question. I did grep through my logs and report files very carefully. Nothing. It stopped at the synth for this module and that was the last module mentioned.  Like I said before, Xilinx doesn't support VHDL simulation anymore, only Verilog. Learning Verilog to simulate this right now is not an option. The issue has been solved and this thread can die. I do realize how important simulation is, but I can not do it due to Xilinx's refusal to implement VHDL simulation in Vivado as they had it in ISE.